# How do update an Parse Object when it is in a relation with anothers Parse Objects

Tags: parse-platform

I have a doubt with **Parse Relations**:

**Example**:
I have objects **Book** and **Author**.
So, a **Book** may have more than one **Author** and one **Author** may have written more than one **Book**.

*The INSERT process in Parse Relations: I understood*.

But, I want to know if when I change an **Author Object** age, for example, will every his **Books** have changed this **Author Object** age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, I want to know if when I change an Author Object age, for
>   example, will every his Books have changed this Author Object age?

Yes.  Consider a real book and a real author.  The relationship -- that this author wrote this book -- is a fact in the world independent of both the book and the author.  When the author ages, the book is now related to an older author.  Relationships in parse (and most databases, and most OO languages by default) work this way.